# Replace a specific text value after call home_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I just started the coding and can't figure this out by myself. Plese help.

example in wordpress

```
<input type="text" name="old" value="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" />
```

printing- https://example.com

Change printing value = http://example.net

Is it possible to change the printing value after calling the home_url in PHP without Jquery?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str_replace` function inline; The `home_url()` return value to `str_replace` as input, then this function replace `com` to `net`, as you need.

```
<input type="text" name="old" value="<?php echo str_replace('com','net',home_url()); ?>" />
```

Comment: @JNC if your problem was solved, mark the answer as accepted to help others that have the same problem.

Comment: also possible to add multiple searches and replacements in the code?

Comment: @JNC yes it's. look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php for more samples. For multiple, you should use the array for search and replacements.

Comment: Thanks, I will study with your link, have a great weekend.

Answer (score 0):

My final answer

```
<input type="text" name="old" value="
            <?php 
            $letters = array('https', 'com'); 
            $fruit   = array('http', 'net');
            $output  = str_replace($letters, $fruit, home_url());
            echo $output; ?>" style="width:600px;" />
```